# Python invalid syntax in print

Tags: python, syntax, printing, python-3.x

Sorry I am not familar with Python...

It gives me the following error message

```
  File "gen_compile_files_list.py", line 36
    print 'java files:', n_src
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I.e. caret points to last quote. What's wrong with it?

OS Windows 7, Python version 3.2.2

Comment: post the code around line 36. perhaps a missing bracket or something else.

Comment: instead of comma, use `+` or it maybe because n_src is not a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Python 3, [print is a function](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function). You need this:

```
print('java files:', n_src)
```

Comment: Is it possible to run python 3 in 2 compatibility mod eor something?

Comment: No it is not. You can do it the other way around, use Python 3 features in Python 2. If you want Python 2 syntax, use Python 2.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, there is [2to3](http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html), which can convert such code to be compatible with Python 3.

Comment: It's worth noting you can have Python 3 and Python 2 installed at the same time.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen Yes there is, but that's not the question that I was asked.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, your comment wasn't wrong, but I felt 2to3 fell under "or something".

Comment: @Matthew pretty much anything falls under "or something" if you want to be like that. 2to3 sounds over the top for a Python novice.

Answer (score 2):

print changed syntax between Python2 and Python3; it is [now a function](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function).

You would need to change:

```
 print 'java files:', n_src
```

to

```
 print('java files:', n_src)
```

Alternatively, you can try converting the code from Python2 to Python3 syntax with the 2to3 tool. [Here is more information on the transition](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PortingPythonToPy3k) if you are interested. This way you can maintain a single code base that works on both versions.

As you are not familiar with python, try installing Python 2 instead and running the code with that.

Answer (score 1):

`print` is a function in Python 3+. So:

```
print ('java files:', n_src)
```